# 2D CFT from sigma models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, non-perturbative, sigma-models

$X$ is a closed manifold with a positive-definite metric $g$.
$M_2$ is a 2D oriented closed manifold with a positive-definite metric $G$ and a compatible volume form $\omega$.
We can then consider the following Euclidean path integral for a $X$-valued scalar field $\phi$ on spacetime $M_2$:
$$\int\mathcal{D}\phi\,\mathrm{e}^{-\mathcal{S}[\phi]}\,,\qquad
\mathcal{S}[\phi]=\frac{1}{2e^2}\int_{M_2}\omega\ \langle G, \phi^*g \rangle\,,$$
or written in components:
$$\mathcal{S}[\phi]=\frac{1}{2e^2}\int_{M_2}\sqrt{|G|}\,d^2x\ \ G^{\mu\nu}g^{ab}\partial_{\mu}\phi_a\,\partial_{\nu}\phi_b\,.$$
Since the coupling $e^2$ is dimensionless, the theory has a chance to become conformal.
At the one-loop level, this requires $X$'s Ricci curvature to vanish.

**Question 1:** What's the sufficient and necessary condition on $X$ (and $g$) for having a conformal field theory?

**Question 2:** What if we add a $\theta$-angle $\in H^2(X,U(1))$ or a Wess-Zumino-Witten term $\in H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$?

(I know these are tough questions even nowadays. So I'm actually asking about the best result we knew so far.)

Comment: For (1), it’s a complicated differential equation written as a power series in $\alpha’$. The leading term is the vacuum EFE. Whether the power series converges, and whether there’s a nonperturbative solution that isn’t just the flat space, I don’t know. Maybe someone more knowledgeable in string theory can comment on this